yt-dlp about section json does not have links
It extracts everything from the youtube about page except the linkedin,x links which is what i am looking for.
I am using: yt-dlp --write-info-json --ignore-no-formats "https://www.youtube.com/@AnnaRunyan/about"
which gives me all the about info without links.
yt-dlp --write-info-json --ignore-no-formats "https://www.youtube.com/@AnnaRunyan/about"

there is no Linkedin info in your sample links. Anyway, how can this be solved with yt-dlp? Those informations are not related to a video, but to the whole channel. You have to scrape it

My Stack Overflow answer 73908946 solves your issue.
